# How to use custom themes on Keycloak Operator deployment on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-operator

I installed Keycloak using [Operator](https://artifacthub.io/packages/olm/community-operators/keycloak-operator) (version 12.0.1). It's using the repository [github repository](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator) Everything worked seamlessly. A keycloak instance has been launched and I could log in using admin credentials. I could see a realm, clients, users, etc working as expected.

But I do have a custom theme that I want to use it. For that, I make the following changes in **my-realm.yaml**.

```
apiVersion: keycloak.org/v1alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  name: my-keycloak
  labels:
    app: my-keycloak
spec:
  instances: 1
  extensions:
    - https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/1.0.4/keycloak-metrics-spi-1.0.4.jar
  externalAccess:
    enabled: False
  podDisruptionBudget:
    enabled: True
---
apiVersion: keycloak.org/v1alpha1
kind: KeycloakRealm
metadata:
  name: my-realm
  labels:
    app: my-realm
spec:
  realm:
    id: "my"
    realm: "my"
    enabled: True
    registrationEmailAsUsername: True
    accountTheme: "account-theme"       // THEMES
    adminTheme: "admin-theme"           // THEMES
    emailTheme: "email-theme"           // THEMES
    loginTheme: "login-theme"           // THEMES
    users:
      - username: "aftab@x.com"
        firstName: "Service"
        lastName: "Account"
  instanceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-keycloak
```

But, I didn't see any of the themes in my realms/my-realm/theme-settings. I can see only the default theme in the select box (i.e. keycloak, base). I am expecting `account-theme`, `admin-theme`, `email-theme`, `login-theme` in their respective select boxes.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am trying to use version 12.0.1 (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator)

Comment: That version does not contain the themes https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/12.0.1/pkg/apis/keycloak/v1alpha1/keycloakrealm_types.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, I didn't see any of the themes in my
> realms/my-realm/theme-settings. I can see only the default theme in
> the select box (*i.e.* keycloak, base). I am expecting account-theme,
> admin-theme, email-theme, login-theme in their respective select
> boxes.

The problem is/was that -- until [yesterday](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/commit/f2d0370290d6abe91724b2536748aa6b1245d1e1) the 26th of January of 2021, commit f2d0370290d6abe91724b2536748aa6b1245d1e1 ([pull request #284](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/pull/284)) -- by default the Keycloak Operator did not recognize the Theme-related fields (*i.e.,* `accountTheme`, `adminTheme`, `emailTheme`, `loginTheme`).

This feature was not deployed on the current latest release (12.0.2), however it is available of master. So you can go from there.