# Keycloak operator: how to add custom theme?

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I would like to know how one can add a custom theme to Keycloak using the Keycloak operator in Kubernetes.
Without using the  operator, it was as simple as adding this parameters to the chart:

```
keycloak:
  keycloak:
    extraInitContainers: |
      - name: theme-provider
        image: gcr.io/cldntventr/keycloak-theme:0.0.32
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
          - sh
        args:
          - -c
          - |
            echo "Copying theme..."
            cp -R /logo/* /theme
        volumeMounts:
          - name: theme
            mountPath: /theme
```

But I have no idea how to achieve the same using the operator.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964205/how-to-configure-custom-themes-for-keycloak-on-kubernetes/66994011#66994011 ?

Comment: Yes! Completely missed that answer! Thanks a lot @dreamcrash

Comment: Btw you might also have to do changes on the Operator side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922655/how-to-use-custom-themes-on-keycloak-operator-deployment-on-kubernetes/65923449#65923449