# Deploying custom Keycloak theme with Operator (v15.1.1 & v16.0.0)

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-operator

I have a theme with a size >1MB (which precludes the configmap-solution provided [as an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922655/how-to-use-custom-themes-on-keycloak-operator-deployment-on-kubernetes)).

This theme has been been packaged according to the [Server Development Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes) - its folder structure is

```
META-INF/keycloak-themes.json
themes/[themeName]/login/login.ftl
themes/[themeName]/login/login-reset-password.ftl    
themes/[themeName]/login/template.ftl
themes/[themeName]/login/template.html
themes/[themeName]/login/theme.properties
themes/[themeName]/login/messages/messages_de.properties
themes/[themeName]/login/messages/messages_en.properties
themes/[themeName]/login/resources/[...]
```

The contents of keycloak-themes.json are

```
{
    "themes": [{
        "name" : "[themeName]",
        "types": [ "login" ]
    }]
}
```

where `[themeName]` is my theme name.

Keycloak is running with 3 instances, its resource spec includes:

```
extensions:
  - [URL-to-jar]
```

Deployment was successful according to the logs of each pod - each log contains a message containing

```
Deployed "[jar-name].jar" (runtime-name : "[jar-name].jar")
```

However, in the admin console, I cannot select the theme from the extension for the login-theme. Creating a new realm via crd with a preconfigured login-theme via spec-entry

```
loginTheme: [themeName]
```

also does not work - in the admin-console, the selected entry for the login-theme is empty.

I may be missing something basic, but it seems like this ought to work [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65923449/16005185) if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Hi, Non java dev here, How to create the .jar file(s) from that folder?

Comment: @SanjayPrajapati - you should use the bash `jar` command - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html).
I personally call `jar cfM [TARGET-PATH}.jar [SOURCE-DIRECTORY-PATH]`

Comment: Thank you and then need to put that .jar file into the providers/ directory? I am using Keycloak 20.0.1, I am confused, then what is the use of creating an archive or zip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is so often the case, an uncaught typo was the source of the error.

The directory-structure must *not* be

- META-INF/keycloak-themes.json
- **themes**/[theme-name]/[theme-role]/theme.properties
- [...]

But instead

- META-INF/keycloak-themes.json
- **theme**/[theme-name]/[theme-role]/theme.properties
- [...]

Given a correct structure, keycloak-operator can successfully deploy and load custom-themes as jar-extensions.